# No permission to download my file from Google Drive

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

I'm getting the following error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/XXXXXXXXXXXX?alt=media returned "The user has not granted the app 123456789 read access to the file XXXXXXXXXXXX.">
```

This is rather strange, as I have authenticated as myself using the OAuth web-authentication method. I can list my files too.

Google lists this error here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#403_the_user_has_not_granted_the_app_appid_verb_access_to_the_file_fileid and suggests that I prompt the user to open the file. Well, the user is me and I have opened this file about 20 times perfectly fine. The error doesn't go away...

Here is my complete example:

```
import os
import httplib2
import io
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
location import Location

CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT ID XYXXYX'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'


OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
OUT_PATH = Location.folder_path + "media/dumps/"
CREDS_FILE ='this_file_is_somewhere.json'

storage = Storage(CREDS_FILE)
credentials = storage.get()

if credentials is None:
    # Run through the OAuth flow and retrieve credentials
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    print('Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url)
    code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
    storage.put(credentials)


# Create an httplib2.Http object and authorize it with our credentials
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

def list_files(service):
    page_token = None
    while True:
        param = {}
        if page_token:
            param['pageToken'] = page_token
        files = service.files().list(**param).execute()
        for item in files['items']:
            yield item
        page_token = files.get('nextPageToken')
        if not page_token:
            break


def download(file_id, path=OUT_PATH):
    request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    file_meta = drive_service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()
    name = file_to_get['name']
    print(file_meta)
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print(int(status.progress() * 100))
    f = open(path + '/' + name, 'wb')
    f.write(fh.getvalue())
    print('File downloaded at', path)
    f.close()


download('XXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

Comment: Although I don't know whether this is a solution for your problem, how about removing the credential file of ``this_file_is_somewhere.json`` and recreating it?

Comment: Try to [Open a picker](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-open#open_files_using_the_google_picker) and prompt the user to open the file, or direct the user to Drive to open the file with the app. You can also try to [Manipulate permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing#manipulating_permissions) for that file.

Comment: @noogui it seems not so easy to understand what a "Picker" is. I found that already confusing when I read through this on the Google documentation. I can open the file, it's my file. It opens fine. I have also made it available to other people in the organisation.

Comment: @Tanaike: your suggestion turned out to be correct. I don't know why, but removing and re-creating the CREDS_FILE did the job.

Comment: @dengar81 I'm glad your problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

All thanks to @Tanaike:

Simply removing the credential file and recreating it solved that problem.